# PHP, HTML and MySqli - how to show all data from specific column in one table row

Tags: php, html

I have a database table called `names`. I have 2 columns there - "id" and "name".
In the column "name" I have some data like:

> Inna
>
> ```
> Petia
> ```
>
> Vaska
>
> Kote
>
> Pepa

I want this data to be shown in a html table like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Inna</td>
    <td>Petia</td>
    <td>Vaska</td>
    <td>Kote</td>
    <td>Pepa</td>
  <tr>    
</table>
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$q= mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM names');

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row as $value) {   
        echo "<td>$value</td> "; 
    }  
echo ' </tr>';
}
```

but this did not work for me!

Comment: for me you code is working fine.. i hope you also have the mysqli connect before: `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','db_name');`

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Your code seems to be working.

Comment: I move echo '<tr>'; and echo '</tr>' outside of the while and the code started to work!

Comment: @BorislavRazvanski If you found the solution to your problem, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Don’t use `SELECT *` if you want the value of one column only. (Then you wouldn’t even had had this problem in the first place – although the `foreach` loop becomes a bit superfluous then …)

Comment: Thank you to all of you guys! I will listen to your advices!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    echo '<tr>';
    //foreach($row as $value) {   
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>"; 
    //    }  
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$q= mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM names');
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
foreach($row as $value) {   
    echo "<td>$value</td> "; 
}  
}
echo ' </tr>';
```

This is the solution of my problem: I just has to put

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '</tr>';
```

outside the while!